# Shorten url for Azure OpenAI reference link

Tags: azure, openapi, chatbot, azure-cognitive-search, azure-openai

Using Azure OpenAI with Azure AI Search to build Chatbot. When we get response from OpenAI, there's this unique feature from Azure, to provide response file url link. It looks quite big and ugly as the response. Is there a way to shorten this url ?

Response prompt gives a long link, is there a way to clean it to tinyurl or something. PDF exist in the object store

Comment: you could for sure use some existing shortener url existing tool but i dont think there is something out of the box

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can shorten the url of your response with `TinyURL API` or any other existing tool.

Below is sample code snippet that will generate a short URL using `TinyURL API`.

```py
import requests
import sys
import traceback
import urllib

def shorten(url_long):
    try:
        URL  =  "http://tinyurl"
        url  =  URL  +  ".com/api-create.php?" \
            + urllib.parse.urlencode({"url": url_long})
        res = requests.get(url)
        print("STATUS CODE:", res.status_code)
        print(" Original Long URL:", url_long)
        print(" Generated Short URL:", res.text)
    except Exception as e:
        raise


if __name__ == '__main__':
    url_long = "https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/ai-services/openai/quickstart?tabs=command-line%2Cpython&pivots=programming-language-studio"
    try:
        shorten(url_long)
    except Exception as e:
        traceback.print_exc()
```

**Output:**

```
STATUS CODE: 200 
Original Long URL: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/ai-services/openai/quickstart?tabs=command-line%2Cpython&pivots=programming-language-studio 
Generated Short URL: Result
```